# Search shows all factories instead of the one i search

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, search

I have a search function in my CodeIgniter app but it does not quite work and i don't know what's the problem because i'm fairly new to CodeIgniter.

My model function:

```
function get_search()
{
    $match = $this->input->post('search');
    $this->db->like('Bedrijfsnaam', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Website', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Email', $match);
    $query = $this->db->get('bedrijven');

    return $query->result();
}
```

My controller functions

```
function search()
{
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('search');
    $this->load->view('footer');
}

function searchresults()
{
    $this->load->model('Bedrijven_model');
    $data['query'] = $this->Bedrijven_model->get_search();
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('searchresults', $data);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

the first function is just for the input field. the second is for the result.

My views:

My searchfield view:

```
<div id="bigcontent">
<h2>Bedrijven zoeken</h3>

<form name="input" action="searchresults" method="get">
<input type="search" name="search" id="search">
<input type="submit" value="Zoeken">
</form>
```

My results page:

```
<div id="bigcontent">
<table>
<tr><th>Bedrijf</th><th>Website</th><th>email</th></tr>
<?php foreach($query as $item):?>
<tr>
<td><?= $item->Bedrijfsnaam ?></td>
<td><?= $item->Website ?></td>
<td><?= $item->Email ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
</table>
</div>
```

Hope someone sees the problem :)

a few screenshots to clear up what i mean:
This is the searchfield:

[image: the search field]

This is the resultpage:

[image: results page]

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting all the results because $this->input->post('search) is empty

You must do one of this things

On your view change the method to post:

```
<form name="input" action="searchresults" method="post">
```

Or if want to keep the form submiting with a get request change your controller to this

```
$match = $this->input->get('search');
```

Just do **one** of this changes and give feedback

Answer (score 1):

You cannot post values to model. Instead of posting, pass it as a parameter from controller itself.

MODEL :

```
function get_search($match)
{
    $this->db->like('Bedrijfsnaam', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Website', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Email', $match);
    $query = $this->db->get('bedrijven');

    return $query->result();
}
```

CONTROLLER :

```
function search()
    {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('search');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }

    function searchresults()
    {
        $match = $this->input->post('search');
        $this->load->model('Bedrijven_model');
        $data['query'] = $this->Bedrijven_model->get_search($match);
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('searchresults', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
```

Pass `$match` from controller.

Comment: So deleting the model function? how do i route the new function in controller to the views?

Comment: @KeesSonnema Don't delete the function. Get the posted value in controller and pass it to model

Comment: I don't really know how to do this right. here's my model function: http://pastebin.com/LRGKVVTs and my controller functions: http://pastebin.com/Pq1ffb6R this is my view: http://pastebin.com/RyMhACJj

Comment: i still shows all factories instead of 1 when i search it. what do i miss in this. the error is gone by the way. thanks for that